# Как сделать так, чтобы Дискорд бот отправлял личные сообщения всем пользователям канала(группы)?

Tags: python, discord, бот

[image: Картинка 1]

Я попытался сделать отправку всем пользователям сервера дискорд, но возникает ошибка при попытке написать *Raid @everyone, эвриван не найдено. Как это исправить?

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

import credits 


client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*")
token = credits.token_bot


#member_list = [] #Список регестраций, пока оставим

@bot.command(name = "Start")
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send('''Привет я игровой бот помощник, я нахожусь в разработке, но уже скоро буду функционировать
    я пока знаю одну команду:
    1) *Map - выслать ссылку на сайт показывающий, где какие ресурсы найти''')


@bot.command(name = 'Map')
async def map(ctx):
    await ctx.send("https://www.newworld-map.com/#/")
    
    
    
@bot.command(name = 'Raid')
async def send_m(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await member.send(f'{ member.name }, Пора на осаду')


bot.run(token)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать так, чтобы Дискорд бот отправлял личные сообщения всем пользователям канала(группы)?

Ответ очень прост. Просто переберите участников на сервере.

```py
@bot.command(name = 'Raid')
async def send_m(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
            try:
                user = await bot.fetch_user(member.id)
                await user.send('Текст, который будет отправляться')
            except:
                print("ЛС закрыто!")
    else:
         user = await.bot.fetch_user(member.id)
         await user.send('Тест')
```

Проверьте, должен работать.

Comment: К сожалению ошибка, но и бот ничего не пишет в лс. Я добавил исправления выше

Comment: Проверьте! Вы поставили запятую в ctx.message.guild.members

Comment: @HillSai, Работает, но почему-то когда я выбираю конкретного пользователя, то смска всё равно приходит всем

Comment: @HillSai Как это пофиксить?

Comment: Посмотрите, изменил ответ.

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер всё работает?

Comment: Я думал, что всё работает, но при отправке смс всем, пишется ошибка everyone,  но как только я пишу *raid, данное сообщение просто повторяется столько раз, cколько человек на канале раза пишется в чат, но не в личные сообщения. Но если отправить конкретному человеку, то всё норм работает

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер, вы не указывайте everyone, если хотите всем

Comment: Найдите меня в дискорд: HelwardSai#7122

Comment: Отправил заявку

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер случайно отклонил, давайте ещё раз.

Comment: Готово, я Nanoxia, но созвонимся в понедельник